# Sectionnumber right in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I'm fortunately allowed to use LaTeX instead of PowerPoint for a teaching lesson but I have to recreate the original design of the PowerPoint slides.

Now I need to bring the section numbers on section frames on the right side of the frame (see picture below).

[image]

How could I achieve that in beamer (background an position of the section text is no problem - i just don't know how to move the section number)?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the number of a section by `\thesection`. It should be positionable the same way you probably do with the section name, but without a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?rq=1) I can only guess ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{
    \begin{frame}
        \thesection
    \end{frame}

}

\begin{document}

    \section{sec1}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec2}

    \begin{frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```